# Can't get all the values multiple select

Tags: html, multiple-select

I'm doing some bug-fix on a legacy project which was developed using Struts2 and JSTL. I have an issue with the multiple select below:

```
<tr class="itemTr">
<td class="formLabel"><span class="spamFormLabel">Tags </span>
</td>
                                <td class="formField"><html:select property="tags"
                                        styleId="tags"
                                        styleClass="baseField" size="1" multiple="true"
                                        style="height:170">
                                        <html:options property="tagsList"
                                            labelProperty="tagsLabelList" styleClass="baseOptions" />
                                    </html:select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

When i request the values on the action class

```
request.getParameter("tags");
```

is just returning the first value I selected. My objective is to return all of them, of course...lol

Comment: In this code I don't see Struts2 or JSTL.

Comment: But can you help me?

Comment: In Struts2 all of them returned by `s:select` if you use `multiple="true"`. I don't understand a question.

Comment: When i select 3 values, is just returning the first i selected.

Comment: Because this code doesn't work, it should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String parreco[] = request.getParameterValues("tags");
```

Using this method I can use all the selected values